# What is the VB.Net equavilent of the following

Tags: c#, vb.net, delegates

I need to convert the following to VB.Net. I tried the online converter and the conversion gives an error

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(parsed["result"].ToString(),
                    new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        /*
                         * Because Aliexpress Api logic is very weird - 
                         * it could return "-" for totalResults field, 
                         * Which is Integer by documentation and common sense
                        */
                        Error = HandleDeserializationError
                    });

 protected void HandleDeserializationError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs errorArgs)
        {
            var currentError = errorArgs.ErrorContext.Error.Message;
            errorArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        }
```

The converted code gives

```
Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of T)(parsed("result").ToString(), New JsonSerializerSettings() With { _
    Key .[Error] = HandleDeserializationError _
})

Protected Sub HandleDeserializationError(sender As Object, errorArgs As ErrorEventArgs)
    Dim currentError = errorArgs.ErrorContext.[Error].Message
    errorArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = True
End Sub
```

The ErrorEventArgs class is defined as

```
  Public Class ErrorEventArgs
        Inherits EventArgs

        Public Sub New(currentObject As Object, errorContext As ErrorContext)

        Public ReadOnly Property CurrentObject As Object
        Public ReadOnly Property ErrorContext As ErrorContext
    End Class
```

Basically I have the converted procedure:

```
Protected Sub HandleDeserializationError(sender As Object, errorArgs As ErrorEventArgs)
            Dim currentError As String = errorArgs.ErrorContext.[Error].Message
            errorArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = True
        End Sub
```

And I need to assign it as an event handler

Something like

```
 Dim s As JsonSerializerSettings = New JsonSerializerSettings()
                s.Error = HandleDeserializationError()
                Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of T)(parsed("result").ToString(), s)
```

Comment: And the error message?

Comment: Its part of the ErrorContext Class

Comment: Updated the descrription

Comment: The text of the error message would be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very similar to the generated code, but there are some changes. I don't know what the generator was doing with `Key`, and I don't think it's necessary to bracket the `Error` keyword in this context.

```vb
Dim Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(OF T)(parsed("result").ToString(), _
                New JsonSerializerSettings With { .Error = AddressOf HandleDeserializationError} )


Protected Sub HandleDeserializationError(sender As Object, ErrorArgs As EventArgs)
    'The first line in this method didn't do anything
    errorArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm... Close. But the parameters are now a problem

Comment: How do you know this? WHAT IS THE ERROR MESSAGE? Anyone who sees the question is gonna want to know the same thing, and you'll keep getting downvotes until you post it.

Comment: If I have the code code exactly as you have it then I have to generate a function : Private Function HandleDeserializationError() As EventHandler(Of ErrorEventArgs)

Comment: The error is: Argument not specified for paramater sender, and  Argument not specified for paramater ErrorArgs